# Rotating a patch to face the camera in Matlab

Tags: matlab, camera, rotation, geometry

This short code plots a flat patch (adapted from Matlab's manual):

```
t = 0:pi/5:2*pi;
figure
x=sin(t); y=cos(t); z=ones(size(x));
patch(x,y,z,'y')
axis equal
```

This results with a nice patch facing the camera:

[image]

However, I want to plot this patch on top of an already plotted 3D object, with the camera set on a fixed arbitrary view. My question is: how to rotate the patch's coordinates so the patch will face the camera and will have the right roll? A correct solution will make the patch look the same from any given arbitrary view (uniform scaling is permitted).

I guess that the camera's position, target and up-vector have to be taken into account, but it's not clear to me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny, but today I was doing exactly the same thing :)

My approach is the following

1. Put your camera somewhere on the positive half of the X axis and set camera target to `(0,0,0)`
2. Draw your object the way you need it
3. Store X, Y, and Z coordinates of your object
4. Use `rotate3d` function and the make callbacks for `ActionPreCallback` and `ActionPostCallback` events of the `rotate3d mode object`
5. You'll need also to provide your routine for 'WindowButtonMotionFcn' event of the active figure

The whole logic works like this.
After you clicked rotate3d icon or call the `rotate3d` function, right after you click the left button on axes to start rotation, the `ActionPreCallback` event is fired. There you have to set flag (`WeAreRotating` in the code below) that rotation started. Then in the 'WindowButtonMotionFcn' callback function you retrieve camera view position using

```
[az,el] = view(ah);
```

function and rotate your object. The rotation is tricky, because you have to set its X, Y, and Z coordinates to the original ones you stored before and apply the `rotate` function to it. Something like this:

```
function fig_WindowButtonMotionFcn_callback(obj,evd)
if getappdata(gca,'WeAreRotating')
    newView = round(get(gca,'View'));
    set( ObjectHandle, ...
        'XData',XData0, ...
        'YData',YData0, ...
        'ZData',ZData0 );
    rotate( ObjectHandle, [1 0 0],-newView(2), RotationOrigin );
    rotate( ObjectHandle, [0 0 1],+newView(1), RotationOrigin );
end
end  % if FogProps.SimpleWhenRotated
```

The `ActionPostCallback` event is triggered when you release the mouse button and finish rotation. There you have to clear the rotation flag so moving your mouse will not change the object until you start rotation again.

Sorry if my explanation is somewhat unclear.
It is a little tricky to arrange all the flags properly, especially if you have several axes on the figure.
Actually, after your question I decided to clean my code and post it to FEX so everyone can use it so there you'll see how I achieved desired behavior.

**UPDATE1**

See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47275-fog3d for full example

Comment: Thank you anandr. What about roll around the viewing axis?

Comment: 'view' doesn't take into account this rotation: sphere; [az,el]=view, camroll(45); [az,el]=view

Comment: Yes, `rotate3d` changes `CameraPosition` property while maintaining `CameraUpVector` property (`view` also ignores it) of current axes while `camorbit` and `camroll` change `CameraUpVector` property too. In this case it should be possible to realign all objects accordingly but I think it will be quite tricky because MatLab does not trigger events when camera is rotated/moved (may be through low-level java). Seems that timer is the only way to achieve this, but this will be far from elegant.